# Customize URL location for loadbalancing nginx

Tags: wcf, nginx, load-balancing

I am new to nginx.

I am having WCF Rest Service listening in the following url,
127.0.0.1:portHere/Service1.svc/RemainingRestURLTemplate.

Here is the config I am having.

```
http {
upstream servers_customserver {
        server 127.0.0.1:62133;             
        server 127.0.0.1:62134;             
        server 127.0.0.1:62135;             
 }

server {
    listen       8090;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /two/ {              
    proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host @server_name;           
    proxy_pass  http://servers_customserver;              
    }
```

}
}

Upon entering localhost:8090/two/, I thought the upstream will work,but the browser reports problem, as in the image.
[image]

But the browser works fine when I have removed the "/two/" from my location, as below.
[image]

So, how to make my upstream to work, only when the user typed the url ends with "/two/".

Could some one share some input on it.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after some hrs, found that trailing slash did the work.
`proxy_pass http://servers_customserver/` works instead of `proxy_pass  http://servers_customserver` Correct me if am wrong.
Thx.